# Import a mysql database using mysql command line

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if it's possible to import a mysql database
using the mysql command line.

Most solutions give mysql -u root -p nameofdatabase < mysqlfile.sql

I was wondering if it's possible to do this inside the 
mysql commmand line, *instead of passing arguments to the executable.*

If I just do

```
 mysql> mydatabase < mysqlfile.sql;
```

That just doesn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
mysql> use nameofdatabase;
mysql> SET autocommit=0 ; source the_sql_file.sql ; COMMIT ;
```

The important part, what you were looking for, is the `source` command. I usually switch off autocommit because of the execution time.

Comment: Is the `source` command doing the same thing (importing) as `<` in command like this, `mysql -u root -t < employees.sql` ?